# Parse SQL results and plot using PHP (Flot or HighChart)

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, highcharts, flot

I have a MySQL database that is recording realtime sensor data.  In my table, I have ID (auto incremented), TimeStamp, and SensorData.   I am recording multiple sensors (pressure, temp, etc...) and storing them all in the SensorData column.  It is space delimited.  So it looks something like:

33.5 108.3 443.2 44.2 779.553

I would like to plot this information on a website in realtime.  So far, I have setup Flot and it will query my DB and return results, but I dont know how to parse out the SensorData column so I can have a plot for each sensor.

The device that is sending data to the SQL server can not be modified, so I will always have multiple sensor entries in one column.  Here is the code I am currently using for Flot:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Flot Examples</title>
    <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
 </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Apex HiPoint, LLC</h1>

    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>

<?php

    $server = "www.freesql.org";
    $user="un";
    $password="pw";  
    $database = "testdb";

    $connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
    $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection);

    $query = "SELECT Id, TME FROM SData";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $dataset1[] = array($row['Time'],$row['SensorData']);
    }
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var dataset1 = <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>;

    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ dataset1 ]);
});
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

So my ultimate goal here is to have one web page that contains multiple plots.  One plot for each sensor in RealTime.  15-30sec updates are OK.  And I can not modify the structure of the database, so all sensor data is contained within that one record.  I am new at php, mysql and these other goodies so please understand.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you know that it will always have a single space between each sensor datum you could SELECT your series data from MySQL splitting the sensor column value on a single space and send it to whatever charting system you want. I am not sure if MySQL has a built in split function but I would check for that (I know that SQL Server does not).

Comment: Thank you for the input.  MySQL does not have a split function that I can find, but that is exactly my goal.  I found the following code:     $result = mysql_query("select SUBSTRING_INDEX(sensors,'\t',1) as sensors, localtme from varia");   This will print out the first sensor value.  If I change "1" to "2", it will print out the first and second values.  I just cant figure out how to split the results.